# \global function makes problems

Tags: errors

I've got a qusetion about \global... 
I've download a template for document settings in LaTex. There are a lot of \global... functions wich when I delete one of them I've this error: "Undefined control sequence. \titlepages" and some info about missing font shape. I don't need them all, so I would like to delete some. How to do it?

```
\documentclass[male, authorStatement, indexNumber, fileVersion, keywords, thanks]{lib/u}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\globalFullAuthor{xxx}                     
\globalShortAuthor{x}                  
\globalFullTitle{Sym}  
\globalShortTitle{Ryn}    
\globalFullUniversity{Uniwer}
\globalShortUniversity{U}                           
\globalDepartment{Wyd}               
\globalDegreeprogramme{Inf}       
\globalThesisType{P}                   
\globalUnderTheSupervisonOf{Po}
\globalSupervisor{prof} 
\globalAcknowledgements{Dla}   
\globalFileVersion{0.9.0}  
\globalIndexNumber{190}  
\globalCity{K}        
\globalYear{2015}          
\globalKeywords{smth}
```

Also got second error: "\begin{itemize} on input line 235 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}"

From what i know it means that I'm missing "\end{itemize}" in page, which is not a true. It pops out with "\end{document}" line. I didn't find any explanation.

Thanks for Your help.

Here's also part of "lib/u.cls" which corresponds to \global:

```
%##############################################################################
% Variables definitions
%##############################################################################
\def\globalFullAuthor#1              {\gdef\@globalFullAuthor{#1}}                
\def\globalShortAuthor#1             {\gdef\@globalShortAuthor{#1}}               
\def\globalFullTitle#1               {\gdef\@globalFullTitle{#1}}                 
\def\globalShortTitle#1              {\gdef\@globalShortTitle{#1}}                
\def\globalFullUniversity#1          {\gdef\@globalFullUniversity{#1}}            
\def\globalShortUniversity#1         {\gdef\@globalShortUniversity{#1}}   

\def\printFullAuthor{\@globalFullAuthor}              % Display
\def\printShortAuthor{\@globalShortAuthor}            % Display
\def\printFullTitle{\@globalFullTitle}                % Display
\def\printShortTitle{\@globalShortTitle}              % Display
\def\printFullUniversity{\@globalFullUniversity}      % Display    
\def\printShortUniversity{\@globalShortUniversity}    % Display
```

Comment: Can you point to to the source of `lib/u.cls`?

Comment: I've edited first post. Sorry for my english, but maybe I didn't understand Your question. Maybe You want me to put full u.cls file?

Comment: `\def\globalFullAuthor#1              {\gdef\@globalFullAuthor{#1}}` is so broken, the class code should really be fixed rather than trying to work around such things in the document. Where did this class come from?

Comment: it isn't possible to recreate the error using these fragments, you need to provide code that people can run that generates the error if you need help fixing the problem.

Comment: you have not shown the full error message but if it is `undefined command \titlepages` note that most classes define an environment `\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}` not a `\titlepages` command.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to recreate the error using the fragments posted but the fragments have an obvious error which could cause weird spurious errors in the document if these `\global...` commands are used, so might possibly be the source of the problem.

```
\def\globalFullAuthor#1              {\gdef\@globalFullAuthor{#1}}                
\def\globalShortAuthor#1             {\gdef\@globalShortAuthor{#1}}               
\def\globalFullTitle#1               {\gdef\@globalFullTitle{#1}}                 
\def\globalShortTitle#1              {\gdef\@globalShortTitle{#1}}                
\def\globalFullUniversity#1          {\gdef\@globalFullUniversity{#1}}            
\def\globalShortUniversity#1         {\gdef\@globalShortUniversity{#1}}
```

should be

```
\def\globalFullAuthor#1{\gdef\@globalFullAuthor{#1}}                
\def\globalShortAuthor#1{\gdef\@globalShortAuthor{#1}}               
\def\globalFullTitle#1{\gdef\@globalFullTitle{#1}}                 
\def\globalShortTitle#1{\gdef\@globalShortTitle{#1}}                
\def\globalFullUniversity#1{\gdef\@globalFullUniversity{#1}}            
\def\globalShortUniversity#1{\gdef\@globalShortUniversity{#1}}
```

as it is the argument to (say) `\globalFullAuthor` is *not* the following `{}` group such as `{xxx}` in your example, it is everything up to the next space (or newline) character. In your example these happen to be the same thing as there is a newline after the `}` of `{xxx}` but if your real document misses those newlines the effect would be predictable but almost certainly unwanted.